# Driver failed programming external connectivty

Tags: jhipster-registry

Sometimes when I start up the Jhipster registry I get this error.

```
 C:\DEV\GITLAB\docker.compose>docker-compose -f jhipster-registry.yml up
    Starting dockercompose_jhipster-registry_1 ... error

ERROR: for dockercompose_jhipster-registry_1  Cannot start service jhipster-registry: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockercompose_jhipster-registry_1 (4d7fb5c0e58ffbe825abc1d6ec7fa07ff19d61916647b8b74e82cf90437da7aa): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8761:tcp:172.19.0.2:8761: input/output error'

ERROR: for jhipster-registry  Cannot start service jhipster-registry: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockercompose_jhipster-registry_1 (4d7fb5c0e58ffbe825abc1d6ec7fa07ff19d61916647b8b74e82cf90437da7aa): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8761:tcp:172.19.0.2:8761: input/output error'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

It looks like it wont start because the port is taken.
So I looked at this with multiple programs

**Attempts:**

*Netstat / Resource monitor / TCPvie*w but none of them could see anything taking up that port.

`docker-compose down`

It is temporary fixed by rebooting windows.
It is also fixed by rebooting docker.

jhipster-registry.yml:

```
 version: '2'
services:
    jhipster-registry:
        image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.2.4
        volumes:
            - ./central-server-config:/central-config
        # By default the JHipster Registry runs with the "dev" and "native"
        # Spring profiles.
        # "native" profile means the filesystem is used to store data, see
        # http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,native
            - SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=something
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=something
            - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_ENABLED=true
            - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_HOST=jhipster-logstash
            - JHIPSTER_METRICS_LOGS_ENABLED=true
            - JHIPSTER_METRICS_LOGS_REPORTFREQUENCY=60
            # - GIT_URI=https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/
            # - GIT_SEARCH_PATHS=central-config
        ports:
            - 8761:8761
```

Comment: Please, post `jhipster-registry.yml`file

Comment: I've added it @AlexGalera

Comment: Have you tried changing in port? Note that specified in `ports` field is a port mapping. So, you can go on using 8761 in jhipster-registry inside container and access with different port from outside. It's thought to difference and route each container with a port. For example, container 1 maps 8762:8761, container 2 maps 8763:8761, and so. Consider I'm only asking you some things, this isn't the final solution because I need some more information, but maybe is useful change `ports 8761:8761` by `ports 8762:8761`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that next time this error pops up

Comment: As of now the error has not occurred yet, since I changed systems.

Comment: The error is back, i tried changing the ports, but that did not resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem on windows / docker

The solution was to restart Docker and test it again